# How these nested `for` loops work in C language?

Tags: c, for-loop

I find it hard to understand how for loops work, specially when there are more than one. If f3(1,-2,1), then what does this function return? also n6=?  The language is C.

```
int f3(int n6, int n7, int n8) {
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i <= n8; i++) {
        for(j = i; j > n7; j--) {
            n6 *= 2;
        }
    }

    return n6;
}
```

The answer shall be 32.

Comment: Please provide comment on downvoting.

Comment: Joe, please gives us a clear question like: I do not fully understand why this function (f3) returns the answer 32 through the use of for lusses? instead of "help"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function takes a number of `int` as input.

`n7` and `n8` are the iteration inputs. Or they provide the loops the length value.

The first `for` loop loops the length of `n8` while `i` is smaller or equal to `n8`

While the second loop takes the current `index` (=i) of the first loop as starting point. It looks if the index is larger than `n7` and than iterates back (j--) by subtracting `one` from the index (j)while `index` is greater than `n7`.

The calculation is made in the iterations of the second loop: it multiplies `n6` by `two`. When the loops are done, it returns the multiplication of `n6` back.

In your case the first loop will run two times:

1. `n8` = 1 and 0 and 1 are less or equal.
2. index `0` becomes the `starting index` of loop 2. `j` = 0 and is greater than n7 (-2).
3. This loop will run two times since 0 and -1 are greater than -2.
4. During that loop `n6` (1) gets multiplied two times by two. or `1 * 2 * 2`
5. The second loop ends and goes back to the first, which runs again because 1 equals 1.
6. Now the index `1` becomes the starting index of loop 2.
7. This loop will run three times since 1, 0, and -1 are greater than -2.
8. Again multiplication: `4 * 2 * 2 * 2`
9. End of loop 1 (two iterations).

`n6` = 32.

This function returns powers of 2 of `n` on a given number of iterations where `n7` needs to be greater than `n8`, else `n6` will be returned unmodified.

---

Since this is almost JavaScript we can demonstrate with example code:

```js
function f3(n6, n7, n8) {
    let i, j;

    for(i = 0; i <= n8; i++) {
        for(j = i; j > n7; j--) {
            n6 *= 2;
        }
    }

    return n6;
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  const n6 = document.querySelector("input.n6").value;
  const n7 = document.querySelector("input.n7").value;
  const n8 = document.querySelector("input.n8").value;
  
  console.log(f3(n6, n7, n8));
});
```

```css
label{
 display: block;
 margin: 2px;
}

label > input{
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<label>Input number <input class="n6"></label>
<label>value 1 <input class="n7"></label>
<label>value 2 <input class="n8"></label>

<button>Start</button>
```